# Printing Pascal's triangle in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pascals-triangle

I just started learning Haskell, and have been doing a few problems online. Most of the times, I can figure out the solution but I am unable to print it out in the output format that is expected.

For example, I tried doing a Pascal's triangle program. I found out how to generate Pascal's Triangle as a list of lists of Ints, but I cant figure out how to print it.

Here is my code.

```
import Data.List
pascal n = map liner [0..n]
    where liner x = map (comb x) [0..x]

comb n 0 = 1
comb 0 r = 0
comb n r = comb (n-1) (r-1) * n `div` r 

main = do
    order <- getLine
    let output = pascal . (read :: String -> Int) $ order
    print output
```

Currently, the output is like

```
[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1]...
```

I want to print it in the form

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
...
```

How do I do this? I have tried using things like mapM_ or intercalate " ", with no luck. I'm not into monads yet so I don't understand how mapM works.

Comment: No need to understand monads for this, really. `f = unlines . map (intercalate " " . map show)` will produce the desired `String` value out of a `[[Int]]` value; simply pass the result to `putStr`.

Comment: and `intercalate " "` is just `unwords` - you you get it with `putStr . unlines . map (unwords . map show)`

Comment: Aah beautiful. I was mixing `lines` and `unlines` and `map` up all wrong. I wasn't using `show` the right way. Thanks!

Comment: @Carsten Ah yes; I was overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different ways to do this, but the most straight forward (IMO) is the following.

```
putStrLn $ intercalate "\n" $ map (intercalate " " . map show) output
```

This first converts all of the numbers in the list into strings (using `show`). Then it converts the innermost lists into strings, where each element is separated by spaces (using `intercalate " "`). Then it converts the *outermost* list into a string where each element is separated by a *newline* (using `intercalate "\n"`). And finally, it pushes the resulting string onto stdout. Replace the last line of your `main` with this and it should do what you want.

EDIT:
As Yakym mentioned in his answer, `intercalate " "` and `intercalate "\n"` can be replaced with `unwords` and `unlines`, making the code above a little more concise (it also removes the need for the import of `Data.List`).

```
putStr $ unlines $ map (unwords . map show) output
```

I changed `putStrLn` to `putStr` because `unlines` automatically adds a newline to the end of the output.

Answer (score 2):

There are also functions like `unlines` and `unwords` that do natural intercalation on string lists.

```
pascal :: [[Int]]
pascal = iterate (\row -> zipWith (+) ([0] ++ row) (row ++ [0])) [1]

printPascal :: [[Int]] -> IO ()
printPascal = mapM_ (putStrLn . unwords . map show)

--*Main> printPascal $ take 10 pascal 
--1
--1 1
--1 2 1
--1 3 3 1
--1 4 6 4 1
--1 5 10 10 5 1
--1 6 15 20 15 6 1
--1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
--1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
--1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```

Comment: `[0] ++ row` could be simplified to `0 : row`

Comment: You are right; I borrowed the line from the Haskell wiki https://wiki.haskell.org/Blow_your_mind - I suppose the above version is due to symmetry.